# How does the index shift work with $\log(1+x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to figure out how to perform an index shift of $\log(1+x)$ given as a series as follows, i.e. from $n = 0$ to $n = 1$.
Maybe someone can explain this to me explicitly.

$$
\log(1 + x) = -\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{(-x)^{k+1}}{(k+1)}.
$$

The series for $n = 0$ should look like this:

$$
\log(1 + x) = \sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}
$$

Comment: Typo! I just fixed it

Comment: You may find it more comfortable to use two variable names. Starting from the first form, let $h=k+1$. The lower bound $k=0$ becomes $h=0+1 = 1$, while the upper bound is still $\infty$:

$$-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{k+1}}{k+1} = -\sum_{h=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{h}}{h}$$

What remains is splitting the $(-x)^h$ into powers of $-1$ and $x$.

Comment: how would you do the splitting part?

Answer (score 0):

Your first series is
$$
-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty-\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+2}x^{k+1}}{k+1}.
$$
And the second series is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}k,
$$
which is identical to the first series, since both of them are the series
$$
x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}x+\cdots
$$